# Double less than Ruby access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am still very new to Ruby and was wondering how I would access a data element stored in a "double less than" structure:

```
@email << {:envelope => envelope, :body => body}
```

If I do

```
<% @results.email.each do |result| %>

  <%= result %>

<% end %>
```

I get

```
bodyTEST TEST envelope#<struct Net::IMAP::Envelope date="Tue, 28 Jun 2011 09:20:35 -0700", subject="TEST TEST", from=[#<struct Net::IMAP::Address name="Some Name", route=nil, mailbox="someinbox", host="somehost.com">], sender=[#<struct Net::IMAP::Address name="Somename", route=nil, mailbox="somebox", host="somedomaincom">], reply_to=[#<struct Net::IMAP::Address name="SomePerson", route=nil, mailbox="somemailbox", host="somehost.com">], to=[#<struct Net::IMAP::Address name=nil, route=nil, mailbox="thisinbox", host="somehost.com">], cc=nil, bcc=nil, in_reply_to=nil, message_id="<C4427977-8A42-46E4-ADB4-1AE88ED9CCDE@mehost.com>">
```

How do access each element, like body, envelope, sender (within envelope)? `result.body` doesn't work, nor does `result[body]`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `result[:body]` and not `result[body]`. `body` is a variable, whereas `:body` is a symbol (similar to a string).

Notice that you have stored values in the hash with symbols. `{:envelope => envelope; :body => body}` is storing the content of the variable `envelope` (the one on the right) as the value against the key `:envelope` (and the same for `body` and `:body`).

Note: This is a nice write up on how Symbols differ from Strings - http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/

Answer (score 1):

```
@email << {:envelope => envelope, :body => body}
```

is simply adding the hash to the `@email` variable. If it is an `Array`, then you are adding an element, otherwise, it depends on the implementation of the `#<<` method. To access the elements, use hash lookup syntax:

```
result[:envelope] #=> returns the envelope object
result[:envelope].sender #=> returns the envelopes sender 
result[:body] #=> returns the body
```

Comment: How do you access the name within the struct `result[:envelope].sender`?

Comment: `result[:envelope].sender.name` should do it

Comment: I'm getting an undefined method.

Comment: I found out it had to be result[:envelope][:sender][0].name